# Codeigniter : delete from 2 tables and image from folder

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I have 2 tables `pengguna` and `dosen`, all i want to do is deleting from 2 tables also delete image from the folder where the uploaded image located, but all i can do is just deleting data from 2 tables but i can't delete the image than has been uploaded, below are my codes.

> CONTROLLER

```
public function delete($id){
    unlink('assets/img/dosen/'.$result->foto_dosen);
    $this->db->delete('dosen',array('id_pengguna'=>$id));
    $this->db->delete('pengguna',array('id_pengguna'=>$id));
    redirect(site_url('dosen/data?balasan=2')); 
}
```

> MODEL

```
function delete($cond){
    $this->db->where($cond);
    $query = $this->db->delete('dosen');
    return $query;
    //DELETE FROM dosen WHERE id=$id
}
```

> VIEW

```
<a class="del btn-floating red tooltipped" href="<?php echo site_url('dosen/delete/'.$result->id_pengguna.''); ?>" class="material-icons" onclick="return confirm('Hapus Dosen?')" data-tooltip="Hapus Dosen" data-delay="1"><i class="material-icons left">clear</i></a>
```

Comment: `echo  $result->foto_dosen;` just above unlink function and check foto_dosen is there or not ???

Comment: i'm sorry i don't really get what u mean, that's the whole my deleting code, no other line of code anymore

Comment: this is my whole controller code https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=86A621A5491BC8A8!19875&authkey=!ABfeod1wzBMyL6Y&ithint=file%2cphp, just look at the delete function, am i doing wrong?

Comment: I"m saying that your unlink function does not work because you don't have valid path to that image .. so thats why i said to print this `$result->foto_dosen`; and check what its is printing...

Comment: i think i know what u mean `$result->foto_dosen` is not recognizeable so the path doesn't exist, is that what u mean?

Comment: yeah, thats what i mean... :)

Comment: can u provide a code how to read that `$result->foto_dosen`? i try to unlink the path manually and it work but to do it dynamically based on the `id` i just don't get the idea :')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110627/discussion-between-manjeet-barnala-and-mirza-chilman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your function with this :

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $query = $this->MDosen->read('dosen',array('id_pengguna'=>$id), null, null);
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $result) 
    {
        unlink('assets/img/dosen/'.$result['foto_dosen']);
    }
    $this->db->delete('dosen',array('id_pengguna'=>$id));
    $this->db->delete('pengguna',array('id_pengguna'=>$id));
    redirect(site_url('dosen/data?balasan=2')); 
}
```

Comment: Well, It worked for as follow: `$query = $this->MDosen->get_where('dosen',array('id_pengguna'=>$id));` `get_where` instead of `read` :)